# Unity is gone after uninstalling webapps?

Tags: unity, 12.10

I removed the package `apt-get remove unity-webapps-facebook`. After restarting, nothing but my desktop icons show. The top menu, and the leftside one is gone.

Opening the terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, and typing `unity` tells me It's been uninstalled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try reinstall unity.

```
sudo apt-get install unity
```

Comment: My problem is, that I can't connect to wifi without the top menu.

Comment: Got cabled and reinstalled.

Comment: Normally ubuntu connects automatic on wifi ;). But I am happy you solved your problem. I always forget that there are laptops where the wifi works.

Comment: I used Ubuntu at my school for the first time today, so it hadn't saved the password there :).